# Attach changes from SourceTree to Collaborator

Tags: git

I have used tortoisehg where I was using the below command to attach my changes to code collaborator,

```
ccollab addhgdiffs <reviewId> -c <revisionId>
```

But now we moved to git with SourceTree, but SourceTree is not showing the revisionId as tortoisehg. So what I can mention in the below command?

```
ccollab addgitdiffs <reviewId> -c <???>
```

Comment: Are you using git or mercurial?

Comment: I ask because you mentioned TortoiseHg in your question which is a Mercurial tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ccollab addgitdiffs <reviewID> <MyCommitId> <PreviousCommitId>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to create a Custom Action in SourceTree, the placeholder `$SHA1` can be used in the "Parameters" edit box to specify the identifier of the commit to use.

Find out more in the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/SOURCETREEKB/Using+Git+in+Custom+Actions).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom action in SourceTree that lets you add a selected commit to Collaborator.

1. In SourceTree, select Tools / Options / Custom Actions.
2. Click Add to create a new custom action.
3. Set up the action as follows:

   **Menu caption**: Add to code review

   **Run command silently**: Unchecked

   **Script to run**: Click the ... button and browse to your Collaborator installation directory. Select ccollabgui.exe and click Open.

   **Parameters**: addchangelist ask $SHA

[image: Edit Custom Action]

Now, whenever you need to launch a code review for a given commit, right-click the commit in SourceTree's Log / History view, and select Custom Actions / Add to code review. This will launch the Collaborator UI, so you can choose to create a new review or add to an existing one, and attach support artifacts as needed.

This works for me with SourceTree 3.0 and Collaborator 11.2.